# Hash of Hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have the question in Perl:Input 5 mobile set details (Invoice number, Model , Company, Memory , Price , Quantity ). Print all the details, total amount (quantity * price) , total quantity , number of mobiles from each company.

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %mobset = (
    '1' => {
        'Invoice No' =>'3456',
        'Model'      =>'S9900',
        'Company'    =>'Sonyericcson',
        'Memory'     =>'1GB',
        'Price'      =>'8000',
        'Qnty'       =>'1',
    },
    '2' => {
        'Invoice No' => '3457',
        'Model'      => 'S3322',
        'Company'    => 'Samsung',
        'Memory'     => '2GB',
        'Price'      => '9000',
        'Qnty'       => '2',
    },
    '3' => {
        'Invoice No' => '3458',
        'Model'      => 'N4140',
        'Company'    => 'Nokia',
        'Memory'     => '512MB',
        'Price'      => '5000',
        'Qnty'       => '2',
    },
    '4' => {
        'Invoice No' => '3459',
        'Model'      => 'S4636',
        'Company'    => 'Samsung',
        'Memory'     => '256MB',
        'Price'      => '6000',
        'Qnty'       => '1',
    }, 
    '5' => {
        'Invoice No' => '3460',
        'Model'      => 'S7854',
        'Company'    => 'Samsung',
        'Memory'     => '128MB',
        'Price'      => '7000',
        'Qnty'       => '1',
    }
);

print "All the mobile set details are as follows:\n";
foreach my $id(sort keys %mobset) {

    print "Mobile SlNo. = $id, Invoice No. = $mobset{$id}{'Invoice No'}, Model No. = $mobset{$id}{'Model'}, CompanyName = $mobset{$id}{'Company'}, Memory = $mobset{$id}{'Memory'}, Price = $mobset{$id}{'Price'}, Quantity = $mobset{$id}{'Qnty'}\n";

    $totqty += $mobset{$id}{'Qnty'};
    $totprice += $mobset{$id}{'Price'};
}

print "Total Quantity of mobile set is $totqty\n";
$totamt = $totqty * $totprice;
print "Total Amount of mobile set is Rs.$totamt\n";

print "The company names of mobile are:\n";
foreach my $id(sort keys %mobset) {

    print "$mobset{$id}{'Company'}\n"; 
}

$name = SonyericcsonSamsungNokiaSamsungSamsung;
my @names = ($name =~ m/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g);
join(',',@names);
my %count;

foreach (@names) {

    if (exists $count{$_}) {

        $count{$_}++;
    } 
    else {

        $count{$_} = 1;
    }
}

print "The number of mobiles from each company are:\n";
foreach (keys %count)  {

    print "$_ \t = $count{$_}\n";
}
```

My output is:

```
All the mobile set details are as follows:
Mobile SlNo. = 1, Invoice No. = 3456, Model No. = S9900, CompanyName = Sonyericcson, Memory = 1GB, Price = 8000, Quantity = 1
Mobile SlNo. = 2, Invoice No. = 3457, Model No. = S3322, CompanyName = Samsung, Memory = 2GB, Price = 9000, Quantity = 2
Mobile SlNo. = 3, Invoice No. = 3458, Model No. = N4140, CompanyName = Nokia, Memory = 512MB, Price = 5000, Quantity = 2
Mobile SlNo. = 4, Invoice No. = 3459, Model No. = S4636, CompanyName = Samsung, Memory = 256MB, Price = 6000, Quantity = 1
Mobile SlNo. = 5, Invoice No. = 3460, Model No. = S7854, CompanyName = Samsung, Memory = 128MB, Price = 7000, Quantity = 1
Total Quantity of mobile set is 7
Total Amount of mobile set is Rs.245000
The company names of mobile are:
Sonyericcson
Samsung
Nokia
Samsung
Samsung
The number of mobiles from each company are:
Sonyericcson = 1
Nokia = 1
Samsung = 3
```

But I am getting the o/p for number of mobiles because I did hardcode the mobile names which I am not supposed to. How can I solve the code?

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify. What is o/p? What would be the expected output? Is "mobile name" same as "Model", and if yes, what were you supposed to do instead of hard coding it?

Comment: Mobile names means Company. Output is perfect. But according to the question, I am not supposed to hardcode -> my $name = "SonyericcsonSamsungNokiaSamsungSamsung"; If I hardcode this, easily I can find the number of mobiles from each company. But I want to print the number of mobiles from each company through the script without hardcoding.

Comment: For formatting code you can use `perltidy` util.

Comment: I am trying to solve this script by hashes only.

Comment: @fxzuz, please, do not change the content of the code, e.g. adding/removing keywords, while reformatting it.

Comment: @hristo-iliev, yeah I see your point, I deleted "my" by mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need for the hard code.  You know the name - its in the hasref you are walking.  Just build up a count array based on the Company value

```
my %count;
foreach my $id (sort keys %mobset) {
    ++$count{$mobset{$id}->{Company}};
}

print "The number of mobiles from each company are:\n";
foreach (keys %count)  {

    print "$_ \t = $count{$_}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the fragment of your code collecting the counts to:

```
my %count;
foreach my $key ( %mobset ) {
   my $name = $mobset{$key}{Company} ;
   $count{$name}++ ;
}
```

Or, better, include it in the previous loop:

```
print "The company names of mobile are:\n";
foreach my $id(sort keys %mobset) {

    my $name = $mobset{$id}{Company}; 
    print "$name\n" ;
    $count{$name}++
}
```

Note that

1. It is OK to drop the quotation marks in the key of an array, so you can write `{Company}` instead of `{'Company'}`, and
2. It is OK to increment an undefined hash element (it will be treated as 0), so no need to check whether the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile names are the names you printed earlier in the `foreach my $id(sort keys %mobset)` loop, aren't they? You can either do another loop like that, or you can save the names in an array during that loop and use that.

Comment: Yes Sir.Thats what I want. Please can you help me with the code?